# How do I style text input by a user?

Tags: css, forms, input

I am trying to apply styles to the text that users enter into a form. There are two things I would like to figure out:

(1) How do I indent/add padding so that the text is not touching the left edge of the element?

(2) How do I change the font and font-size of the text?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cRLy.png) is an image of the current form element and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU71q.png) is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Helps if you post some code that you have but you basically create a css class and add padding to your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply padding to your element in your stylesheet, either give it a class name or style the `input` itself. I added some different colors in there just to show you that you can style it different ways.

```css
.my-input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="some text value" class="my-input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input{
 padding-left:7px;
 font-style:italic;
 font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text"></input>
</form>
```